# F# Excel type provider throws System.InvalidCastException when reading empty cell

Tags: f#, type-providers

I am using the F# [Excel Type Provider](http://fsprojects.github.io/ExcelProvider/). The little sample code I took from the documentation works fine until I have an empty cell.

```
let valueA = row.ColumnA
```

This then throws `System.InvalidCastException`

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in sample.exe
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull'
>   to type 'System.String'.

I have fixed this with this code:

```
let mutable valueA = Unchecked.defaultof<string>
    try
        valueA <- row.ColumnA
    with ex -> 
        valueA <- String.Empty
```

This is not very nice code. At least I would like to create a function like this, but then this throws the same `InvalidCastException`?

```
let getString (value : Object) =  
     match value.GetType() = typeof<String> with
        | true -> value.ToString()
        | false -> String.Empty     

let valueA = getString row.ColumnA
```

**Edit**: It seems that being new to F# I misunderstood what was going on, the Excel Type Provider wasn't returning DbNull, it was actually throwing the exception. So this does fix the problem:

```
let getString func =  
     try
        func()
     with ex -> 
        String.Empty
let valueA = getString (fun() -> row.ColumnA)
```

I guess my question now is shouldn't the type provider be retuning the option type so it can handle missing values without throwing exceptions? Or am I still missing something and there is another more elegant way of handling this?

Comment: Looking at the example you linked, it appears that `<null>` is the intended behaviour (but I haven't used the library, so there might be a way to get it to return option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this was actually a bug in the type provider, and it has been fixed in the latest version. It was not supposed to throw an exception when returning data from a perfectly valid excel file, it is returning `null` now.